# AWS AppSync and Ionic Framework- Mutation not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I am using Aws AppSync with Ionic framework. I tried checking the chat application which is provided by AWS Samples. Mutation call is called only once and there is no post call after that in the network calls. I dont know what the exact problem is, whether it is regarding the cache or the socket connection.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';
import appSyncConfig from './aws-export';
import { ApolloModule, Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class GraphqlService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {
  }

  hydrated() {
    const appsyncClient = new AWSAppSyncClient({
      url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
      region: appSyncConfig.region,
      auth: {
        type: appSyncConfig.authenticationType,
        apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey,
      }
    });
    this.apollo.setClient(appsyncClient);
    return appsyncClient.hydrated();
  }

}
```

```js
 send(input: any) {
    const chat = {
      userId: input.userId,
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
      message: input.message,
    };
    this.chats.next([...this.chats.getValue(), chat]);
    this.apollo.mutate({mutation: post, variables: chat}).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: When you say `Mutation call is called only once and there is no post call after that in the network calls`, does that mean mutation did occur? Do you expect it to be called multiple times?

Comment: I have been calling it again , and its not posting data into the dynamoDB

Comment: Is it actually making the network call?

Comment: Its actually making only one call, I have used AWS Amplify and changed the client side code.